# Issues with Cloud Front module with restrictions

Tags: amazon-web-services, module, ansible, amazon-cloudfront, restriction

I am working on getting some geo_locations blacklisted with Ansible in Cloud Front.  I have been able to successfully grab the distribution Ids and show the cloudfront summary with these IDs looping into the `distribution_id` field.

```yaml
- name: Get Distributions
      cloudfront_info:
        aws_access_key: "{{access}}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{secret}}"
        security_token: "{{security}}"
        distribution_id: item
      loop: "{{cloudfront}}"
      register: info
```

But when I call the same module with the restrictions class it tells me no such distribution.

```yaml
- name: Add restrictions
      cloudfront_distribution:
        aws_access_key: "{{access}}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{secret}}"
        security_token: "{{security}}"
        distribution_id: item
        restrictions:
          geo_restriction:
            restriction_type: "blacklist"
            items:
              - "CU"
              - "NI"
        state: present
      loop: "{{cloudfront}}"
```

Here is the full error

```yaml
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: NoSuchDistribution: An error occurred (NoSuchDistribution) when calling the GetDistribution operation: The specified distribution does not exist.
failed: [localhost] (item=xxxxxxx) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "boto3_version": "1.10.12", "botocore_version": "1.14.9", "changed": false, "error": {"code": "NoSuchDistribution", "message": "The specified distribution does not exist.", "type": "Sender"}, "item": "xxxxxx", "msg": "Error describing distribution: An error occurred (NoSuchDistribution) when calling the GetDistribution operation: The specified distribution does not exist.", "response_metadata": {"http_headers": {"content-length": "294", "content-type": "text/xml", "date": "Fri, 10 Apr 2020 15:42:55 GMT", "retry_attempts": 0}}
```

From what I can tell it should work since a basic command uses the came IDs and completes.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue. Needed to split out the distribution_id objects as it did not like the array.